# Show via direct proof that $k(k+1)(k+2)$ is divisible by $6$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

How do I show via direct proof that $k(k+1)(k+2)$ is divisible by $6$. I showed it was divisible by $2$ because at least one of the multiples is even but could not figure out how to show it is divisible by $3$. I tried making $k$ even or odd and substituting $2q$ or $2q+1$ but have not made much progress. Does anyone have any tips as to what direction I should take? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: exactly one of $n$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $n$.

Comment: look at $k+2 \choose k-1$ (if it counts as a direct proof)

Comment: How about three consecutive numbers have the form $3k, 3k+1, 3k+2$?  Or $3k-1, 3k, 3k+1$, or finally, $3k-2, 3k-1, 3k$...

Comment: Just relate it to $\Bbb Z_3=\{[0],[1],[2]\}$

Comment: $k(k+1)(k+2)=6\binom{k+2}{3}$ :P

Comment: Why is at least one of the *factors* even?  Why can't they all be odd?  Can you modify that to argue that one of the factors must be divisible by 3?  Is i possible that $k$ is not divisible by 3?  If so then can $k +1$ not be divisible by 3.  If so would it then be possible for $k +2 to be divisible by 3?  Hint what is the remainder of k/3?  What is the remainder of (k+1)/2?  What is the remainder of (k+2)/3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the division algorithm, $k$ divided by $3$ yields a remainder of $0$, $1$, or $2$. In other words, there are some integers $q,r$ such that $k=3q+r$ where $r=0,1,$ or $2$.

If $r=0$, then $k=3q$ is divisible by $3$. If $r=1$, then $k+2=(3q+1)+2=3(q+1)$ is divisible by $e$. If $r=2$, then $k+1=(3q+2)+1=3(q+1)$ is divisible by $3$. Therefore, in all cases, at least one of $k$, $k+1$, and $k+2$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could not ask for a better explanation!

Comment: Glad to help. When you need to prove a  "low level" fact about the integers (like at least one of three consecutive integers is divisible by 3), the division algorithm is probably your best tool. :)

Comment: @user6797501 if you like an answer, upvote it. accept the best one. this is how you say thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $k = 6a+b$,
where $0 \le b \le 5$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
k(k+1)(k+2)
&= k(k^2+3k+2)\\
&= k^3+3k^2+2k\\
&= (6a+b)^3+3(6a+b)^2+2(6a+b)\\
&= (6a)^3+3((6a)^2b+6ab^2)+b^3+3(36a^2+12ab+b^2)+12a+2b\\
&= 6(6^2a^3+18a^2b+ab^218a^2+6ab+2a)+b^3+3b^2+2b\\
&= 6(6^2a^3+18a^2b+ab^218a^2+6ab+2a)+b(b+1)(b+2)\\
\end{array}
$

By directly computing
$b(b+1)(b+2)$
for $0 \le b \le 5$,
the values are all divisible by $6$
(they are
$0, 6, 24, 60, 120, 210$).

Therefore,
the product is
always divisible by $6$,
being the sum
of two terms
each of which
is divisible by $6$.